# Automatic generation of AC_CONFIG_FILES input

Tags: unix, build-automation, autotools, autoconf

When creating a configure.ac file the standard practice seems to be to explicitly hard code a list of Makefiles that should be created from the corresponding Makefile.in. However it seems like this should not be necessary, the list could easily be generated from some sort of glob specification (e.g. `*/Makefile.in`) or from a shell command (e.g. `find -name Makefile.in`).

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like this facility is built into autoconf! I'm new to m4 but I haven't come across anything about running shell commands to generate m4 input values. Obviously it can be hacked by generating the configure.ac file by `cat`-ing together files and shell commands but this seems unnecessarily complex.

Is there a standard way of doing this? If not then why not? Are there any issues?

Comment: One of the reasons you **don't** want to do this is if you add a new file that should be generated by `AC_CONFIG_FILES`, it won't get built when you run `make`. When you list the files explicitly, adding a new template changes `configure.ac`, which forces re-runs of (among others) `autoconf` (to rebuild `configure`), `configure` (to rebuild `config.status`) and `config.status` (to rebuild the template outputs).

Comment: You can probably hack up something using `m4_esyscmd`, but please don't.

Comment: You don't need to generate `configure.ac`.  If you insist, use a `find` command and place the result in the argument list of `AC_CONFIG_FILES`, but do not automate that process.  This is something that should happen very rarely in the life of the project (ie, once), and should be monitored by a human.  Any changes made to that list should be done by hand to help prevent build bloat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the comments I ended up doing this anyway. What I didn't mention in the question is that this autogeneration was already being done, but in a very ad-hoc way (`cat`ing together various files, some of which were generated on the fly, to create configure.ac) and I just wanted to clean it up.

In the build script we have:

```sh
confdir="config/configure.ac_scripts"

# Generate a sorted list of all the makefiles in the project, wrap it into
# an autoconfigure command and put it into a file.
makefile_list="$(find -type f -name 'Makefile.am' \
                | sed -e 's:Makefile\.am:Makefile:' -e 's:^./::' \
                | sort)"

# A bit more explanation of the above command:
# First we find all Makefile.ams in the project.
# Then we remove the .am using sed to get a list of Makefiles to create. We
# also remove the "./" here because the autotools don't like it.
# Finally we sort the output so that the order of the resulting list is
# deterministic.


# Create the file containing the list of Makefiles
cat > "$confdir/new_makefile_list" <<EOF
# GENERATED FILE, DO NOT MODIFY.
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
$makefile_list
])
EOF
# In case you haven't seen it before: this writes the lines between <<EOF
# and EOF into the file $confdir/new_makefile_list. Variables are
# substituted as normal.

# If we found some new dirs then write it into the list file that is
# included in configure.ac and tell the user. The fact that we have
# modified a file included in configure.ac will cause make to rerun
# autoconf and configure.
touch "$confdir/makefile_list"
if ! diff -q "$confdir/new_makefile_list" "$confdir/makefile_list" > /dev/null 2>&1; 
then
    echo "New/removed directories detected and $confdir/makefile_list updated,"
    echo "./configure will be rerun automatically by make."
    mv "$confdir/new_makefile_list" "$confdir/makefile_list"
fi
```

Then in configure.ac we have:

```
# Include the file containing the constructed AC_CONFIG_FILES([....]) command
m4_include([config/configure.ac_scripts/makefile_list])
```

instead of writing the Makefile list in directly.

The full source code is [here](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/oomph-lib/blob/working/autogen.sh#L246) and [here](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/oomph-lib/blob/working/configure.ac#L2100).